# Woocommerce: how to display only scheduled sale products

Tags: woocommerce

Dear StackOverflow friends,
I use this Woocommerce shortcode

> [sale_products per_page="12"]

to show only products on sale on a page. This shortcode works perfectly and filter only products on sale, both simple and variable items.

Now I'd like to obtain the same result but I need to show only scheduled sale products, in other words, only the products whose sale price is scheduled in

> Wordpress > products > general > sale price > schedule

I tried to find the differences in output between 'normal sale products' and 'scheduled sale products', but unfortunately I noticed nothing.

Thank for your help!

=================================

Ok, for future reference here is the complete working code. Thanks to @Palmered who solved my issue!

I added this code in my functions.php

```
/* This creates a Woocommerce shortcode for displaying only scheduled on sale products, both simple and variable ones */

function scheduled_sale_products( $atts ) {
        global $woocommerce_loop,$wpdb;

        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'per_page'      => '12',
            'columns'       => '4',
            'orderby'       => 'title',
            'order'         => 'asc'
        ), $atts ) );

        // Get products on sale
        $product_ids_raw = $wpdb->get_results(
"SELECT posts.ID, posts.post_parent
FROM `$wpdb->posts` posts
INNER JOIN `$wpdb->postmeta` ON (posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
INNER JOIN `$wpdb->postmeta` AS mt1 ON (posts.ID = mt1.post_id)
WHERE
    posts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND  (mt1.meta_key = '_sale_price_dates_to' AND mt1.meta_value >= ".time().") 
    GROUP BY posts.ID 
    ORDER BY posts.post_title ASC LIMIT 0,12");

$product_ids_on_sale = array();

foreach ( $product_ids_raw as $product_raw ) 
{
    if(!empty($product_raw->post_parent))
    {
        $product_ids_on_sale[] = $product_raw->post_parent;
    }
    else
    {
        $product_ids_on_sale[] = $product_raw->ID;  
    }
}
$product_ids_on_sale = array_unique($product_ids_on_sale);

        $meta_query   = array();
        $meta_query[] = WC()->query->visibility_meta_query();
        $meta_query[] = WC()->query->stock_status_meta_query();
        $meta_query   = array_filter( $meta_query );

        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'    => $per_page,
            'orderby'           => $orderby,
            'order'             => $order,
            'no_found_rows'     => 1,
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'post_type'         => 'product',
            'meta_query'        => $meta_query,
            'post__in'          => array_merge( array( 0 ), $product_ids_on_sale )
        );

        ob_start();

        $products = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', $args, $atts ) );

        $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $columns;

        if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

        <?php endif;

        wp_reset_postdata();

        return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $columns . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
    }
add_shortcode( 'scheduled_sale_products', 'scheduled_sale_products' );
```

now the new Woocommerce shortcode is ready to use

```
[scheduled_sale_products per_page="12"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is:

Copy the sale_products shortcode into you theme(functions.php) or a custom plugin(a php-file inside the plugins folder). Copy the full function named sale_products from /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-shortcodes.php. It starts around line 560.

Step 1: Copy everything between

```
public static function sale_products( $atts ) {
    global $woocommerce_loop;
```

And

```
    return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $columns . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
}
```

Into your theme or plugin.

Step 2: Change the function declaration from

```
public static function sale_products( $atts ) {
```

to

```
function scheduled_sale_products( $atts ) {
```

Step 3: Hook the shortcode into wordpress.

```
add_shortcode( 'scheduled_sale_products', 'scheduled_sale_products' );
```

Step 4: Alter the query.

Replace this line:

```
$product_ids_on_sale = wc_get_product_ids_on_sale();
```

With:

```
$product_ids_raw = $wpdb->get_results(
"SELECT posts.ID, posts.post_parent
FROM `$wpdb->posts` posts
INNER JOIN `$wpdb->postmeta` ON (posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
INNER JOIN `$wpdb->postmeta` AS mt1 ON (posts.ID = mt1.post_id)
WHERE
    posts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND  (mt1.meta_key = '_sale_price_dates_to' AND mt1.meta_value >= ".time().") 
    GROUP BY posts.ID 
    ORDER BY posts.post_title ASC LIMIT 0,12");

$product_ids_on_sale = array();

foreach ( $product_ids_raw as $product_raw ) 
{
    if(!empty($product_raw->post_parent))
    {
        $product_ids_on_sale[] = $product_raw->post_parent;
    }
    else
    {
        $product_ids_on_sale[] = $product_raw->ID;  
    }
}
$product_ids_on_sale = array_unique($product_ids_on_sale);
```

Now you should be able to use the shortcode like this:

```
[scheduled_sale_products per_page="12"]
```

Comment: What a detailed answer! Thank you @Pekz0r! I tried to apply your suggestion to my code but I can't see any product. I edited my question adding my steps, trying to apply correctly your idea. Thanks again for the time you spent for me :)

Comment: I'm sorry I made a misstake in step 2 and 3. I've edited the post, so please revisit step 2 and 3 to make sure it is like above. Get back to me again if it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi @Pelmered thanks again! 
I edited the code, following your new guidelines. 
Now I can see four products, but only one of them is a scheduled sale product. 
The other products shown are some item simply on sale. I don't know why these appear here and others not (and there are also other sale products and other scheduled sale products not shown with this shortcode). I'm trying to find the association betweeen the items shown!

Comment: Ok, then we are probably almost there. There seams to be something with that meta_query, but I'm not sure exactly how do write it.

I will need to test this code myself.

Comment: Great @Pelmered, thank you! I'm looking for a fix, too! I tried to explicitate a date, to use current_time, to change < to > and '_sale_price_dates_to' to '_sale_price_dates_from'. Also trying to find a sort of 'sale_price_end_date' or similar, but no result up to now! :)

Comment: Hi @Pelmered, I finally realise that the meta_query just edited is near our goal with 'key' => '_sale_price_dates_to',    'value' => time(), 'compare' => '>=''
The only problem is that it shows only simple scheduled onsale products and not the variable ones! If you have time, you can see my new attempts in the post! Goodnight!

Comment: I found a solution! I edited my post so redo the process step by step.

Comment: Good evening @Pelmered! I redid the process twice but I receive this Fatal error: Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object about this line `$product_ids_raw = $wpdb->get_results` 
Looking on the web, I tried to apply this suggestion [http://wordpress.org/support/topic/call-to-a-member-function-get_results-on-a-non-object]
and so 

`function scheduled_sale_products( $atts ) {
  global $woocommerce_loop;`
  
became

`function scheduled_sale_products( $atts ) {
  global $woocommerce_loop,$wpdb;`
   and it WORKS! ;) Thanks a lot for your time, you're great!!! Now I refresh our post!

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Good that you figgured it out yourself :)